# Django 1.6 CSRF 403 errors

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, csrf, django-1.6

I have a site that is running Django 1.6.10. Recently some of our admins had trouble logging in and were getting the CSRF 403 error page. They had to delete all their cookies for the site to be able to login again. This led me to wonder if it was more widespread, since the CSRF error page doesn't get logged. I enabled logging and I'm seeing about 10% of posts having issues.

```
Settings.py:
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.debug',
'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
'django.core.context_processors.media',
'django.core.context_processors.request',
'django.core.context_processors.static',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',

'linaro_django_pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',

'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

The views causing the issue are generic class based views with a comment post form. The form has {% csrf_token %} inside the form tags. The error that is getting triggered is REASON_NO_CSRF from the csrf middleware.

```
<WSGIRequest
path:/accounts/login/,
GET:<QueryDict: {u'next': [u'/profile/edit/']}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {u'username': [REDACTED], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken':     
[u'Ns42nlyOUgLRUatcjjr0cfpRYwVSDETk'], u'password': [u'REDACTED']}>,
COOKIES:{'HIRO_COOKIE':     
'data=&newSession=false&id=REDACTED&timestamp=1414023546237',
'OX_plg': 'swf|shk|pm',
'SS_ARE_Override.traceLevel': 'WARN',
'__gads':   
'ID=b5f389086388b528:T=1413419752:S=ALNI_MaqCqguvaHWhG76FGjhHzPTieaGeA',
'__qca': 'P0-2120806691-1413419758360',
'__sonar': '749077714819215977',
'_bsef2f5b6aaad756f2445ed7606b648325': '1',
'acudeoSession.': '%7B%22time%22%3A1421376382060%2C%22adIndex%22%3A1%7D',
'ebNewBandWidth_.www.REDACTED.com': 'REDACTED',
'mlUserID': '9X8L0kMS8ypL',
'targus.BirthYear': '',
'targus.ap_seg': '',
'targus.gender': '',
'targus.matched': '1',
'targus.segment': '000',
'targus.zip': '',
'vsl_userid': 'c4ee281a94b19b5cb09d83ee93e98f55'},

META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '92',
'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'CV5Vh0mpa578LnKGK1Lfj6pRVB1cwc6E',
'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs',
'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
'HTTP_ACCEPT':     

'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;
q=0.8',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en,en-GB;q=0.8',
'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',
'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
```

What's common with all of the errors is that the Cookie section is missing the csrftoken that should be there. I can't figure out why django isn't always pushing out cookies on the view because it is a class-based view and I have everything setup in settings.py the way the django docs says. This also happens when people try to login or basically any posts.

Comment: Appears to only be happening with chrome user agents.

Comment: saaaame. I double checked and there is indeed a csrf token, but I don't know if its incorrect or how to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug is described here. This is a bug in python.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24492

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I applied the patch to a localized version of Cookies.py and I think it's fixed the errors I was seeing.

Comment: so mark my answer as complete then wtf i need that internet money baby. i downgraded back to the LTS.